# How to get an output thats not an error when user inputs 0

Tags: c#, visual-studio

this is my first real program and I know its not pretty but I'm proud I did it. If the user inputs 0 as an interest rate it does not put out a Value for monthly payment. How do I fix this?

```
    private void buttonPayment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        double sellPrice = 0;
        double stateTax = 0;
        double totalFinanced = 0;
        double amtTax = 0;
        double docFee = 179;
        double tagFees = 0;
        double tradeAllowance = 0;
        double interestRate = 0;
        double taxableAmount = 0;
        double rebate = 0;
        double cashDown = 0;

        // Used For Payments
        double term = 0;
        double monthlyRate = 0;
        double monthlyPayment = 0;
        double topNumber1 = 0;
        double topNumber = 0;
        double bottomNumber = 0;
        double topNumber2 = 0;
        double totalInterest = 0;
        double interestCharge = 0;

        sellPrice = Double.Parse(textBoxSellPrice.Text);
        tradeAllowance = Double.Parse(textBoxTradeAllowance.Text);
        tagFees = Double.Parse(textBoxTagFees.Text);
        rebate = Double.Parse(textBoxRebate.Text);
        interestRate = Double.Parse(textBoxRate.Text);
        term = Double.Parse(textBoxTerm.Text);
        cashDown = Double.Parse(textBoxCashDown.Text);


        interestRate = interestRate * .01;
        monthlyRate = interestRate / 12;


        if (comboBoxState.Text.Contains("NJ"))
        {
            stateTax = .06875;
        }

        if (comboBoxState.Text.Contains("DE"))
        {
            stateTax = .0425;
        }

        if (comboBoxState.Text.Contains("PA"))
        {
            stateTax = .06;
        }


        //Calculatations

        taxableAmount = sellPrice - tradeAllowance;
        amtTax = taxableAmount * stateTax;
        totalFinanced = (amtTax + taxableAmount + docFee + tagFees - rebate - cashDown);

        //Calculates Payments

        topNumber1 = 1 + monthlyRate;
        topNumber2 = Math.Pow(topNumber1, term);
        topNumber = monthlyRate * topNumber2;
        bottomNumber = topNumber2 - 1;
        totalInterest = topNumber / bottomNumber;

        monthlyPayment = totalFinanced * totalInterest;
        interestCharge = (monthlyPayment * term) - totalFinanced;

        // Prints to the labels

        labelTax.Text = amtTax.ToString(format: "0.00");
        labelAmtFinanced.Text = totalFinanced.ToString(format: "0.00");
        labelDocFee.Text = docFee.ToString(format: "0.00");
        labelTagFees.Text = tagFees.ToString(format: "0.00");
        labelMonthlyPayment.Text = monthlyPayment.ToString(format: "0.00");
        labelInterestCharge.Text = interestCharge.ToString(format: "0.00");
    }

    private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearAllText(this);
        ClearAllCombo(this);
        ClearAllmasked(this);
        labelTax.Text = "---";
        labelDocFee.Text = "---";
        labelTagFees.Text = "---";
        labelAmtFinanced.Text = "---";
        labelMonthlyPayment.Text = "---";
        labelInterestCharge.Text = "---";
    }
```

I know its sloppy :(

Thanks again!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MaksimSimkin have you even read the text he wrote? he also describes a problem there

Comment: Use `double.TryParse` if you are parsing user-input

Comment: @Maksim - I disagree; there's a part of it that's on-topic ("*If the user inputs 0 ... How do I fix this?*").  The rest is off-topic, though, and quite a bit can be done to reduce the code to a [mcve] that demonstrates the on-topic question.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer -- Well, then that's a different question and belongs in a different post.

Comment: Im still asking how to convert a monthly payment when user input's 0. Right now it outputs nothing.

Comment: ok,  i have rectracted my close vote

Comment: @rory.ap i agree that this should be 2 different posts, but no beginner is perfect so lets take it as it is and for the next time he knows better

Comment: @NickMesser firstly, if this is your first real app, kudos to you, Ive seen a lot lot worse as a first app. So.. the problem is if your interest rate is 0, either its likely throwing an error, or, producing a 0.. chances are it errors on monthlyrate = interestrate/12, 0/12 ... cant happen..   you need to decide what you want it to do and maybe do an "if interestrate==0 do <stuff> else do <calculations already at hand>"

Comment: @MaksimSimkin for future reference, please read [a guide to CR for SO users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788). TL;DR: "because it belongs on Code Review" is not a valid close reason, and a question that contains code that doesn't work as intended (as is clearly the case here), is off-topic on CR.

Comment: edited to be more relevant to the issue. I will ask my other question elsewhere. I tried making a if interestRate ==0 and could not figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: @NickMesser have you tried running in a debugger and stepping through the code. Examining the values of each variable as you do this will probably help you to understand what is going on, and will give you valuable experience in debugging code

Comment: @NickMesser I think you could be ending up with bottomNumber == 0, which will cause a divide by zero exception

Comment: @RobinHames this does not throw an error during compiling. It works when user input any value over 0. I have tested it at every step over 0 to make sure the calculations are correct. Im working tosee if I can put an if else statement together for this. Having a hard time though. I have put everything together in one class so its very confusing to read. My next step is to separate this a little better for future use.

Comment: @BugFinder Thanks! its sloppy but I managed to figure it out with an if else statement. I could of probabaly did it better but its functioning and I guess that is all the matters.